# how can i search for a specific word in python?

Tags: python, regex, string

Is there a way to search a specific word in python, like 'or'. 
I did this:

```
word = raw_input("what do you want to search? ")
for filee in open('text.txt'):
   if word in filee:
     print "found"
```

But it looks for the string 'or'. For example; if the word 'world' exists in text.txt or some other word containing the 'or' string it prints "found"

Is there a way to search only for that specific word 'or' ?

Comment: You mean search for the word 'or'?  Then you really want to search for ' or '.  If you want to be more correct, you should search for '<non_alpha>or<non_alpha>' so that things like '1or2' and ' or!' would come back, if that's what you want.

Answer (score 10):

Use `regex` with word boundaries:

```
>>> import re
>>> r = re.compile(r'\bor\b')
>>> r.search('and or not')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f2f7f8b2ed0>
>>> r.search('and xor not')
```